# Google search to retrieve number of results for search keywords

Tags: python, api, search, search-engine

I am having a list of keywords and would like to know the number of results for google search for each of those(for my research project). I am using the below code for the same.

```
def showsome(searchfor):
    hits = -1
    try:
            query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
            url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
            search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
            search_results = search_response.read()
            results = json.loads(search_results)
            data = results['responseData']
            print 'Total results for %s: %s' % (searchfor,data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
            hits = int(data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
    except:
            #error.write(formatExceptionInfo())
            traceback.print_exc(file=error)
            error.write("\n")

    return hits
```

But after some 1000 results, I am not getting any results. Is there an alternative way to query google? I checked google custom search API and it allows only 100 results per day.

Comment: The Custom Search docs say: "The API provides 100 search queries per day. **If you need more, simply request additional quota from the [Google APIs] console**."

Comment: I think custom search API is mainly for websites and not for other purposes. So, I am not sure if my request will be accepted.

Comment: If Google rejects your request, you could try scraping the search results page (`http://www.google.com.br/search?q=KEYWORD`, where KEYWORD is the keyword _without quotes_). Not the most elegant (or even ethical?) solution, but gets the job done.

Comment: Scraping `http://www.` doesn't work. Google detects it and says 'Violation of Terms of use'.

Comment: Did u find the solution, could you please paste the working copy of the full code