# Getting number of Google hits for a larger list of words

Tags: python, search

I saw some relevant questions for my problem, but no specific answer. In brief, I have a larger list of words (more than 1000), and I would like to get number of Google hits for each word.
In particular, I read this tread at [Stackoverflow: Google search to retrieve number of results for search keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785833/google-search-to-retrieve-number-of-results-for-search-keywords). But the question of how to handle large list is still open.
Please, I would really appreciate if anyone can trow some piece of Python code whit which I could play and build script.

Comment: It's not a matter of "code" here, it's a matter of whether or not you can convince google to let you search them more than 100 times per day. The code remains the same.

Comment: Google itself does not have the accurate hit count due to it being computationally intensive and being unimportant to the searcher. The number in the search result page is just an estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, then, what to do? I know that Wiki can be downloaded, and then searched for strings, but I do not need it for English, and then, word base is not so large. I heard that people used BING for similar purposes, but I doubt that it could be better than Google -- with more accurate counts.

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to this comment on the aforementioned question:

> If Google rejects your request, you could try scraping the search results page...

I would strongly recommend *not* doing that, especially if you have huge numbers of words to process. However, for *instructive* purposes, this is the code that would ordinarily work for you:

```
import urllib2
import re

def results(word):
    text = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/search?q=%s'%word).read()
    m = re.search('About ([0-9,]+) results', text)
    if m is None:
        return None
    else:
        return int(m.group(1).replace(',', ''))   # remove commas and int-ify
```

I say "ordinarily" because, in my testing, instead of a search results page, I received a polite request from Google:

> **403.** That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL `/search?q=foo` from this server.

I determined that Google knows to reject my request by looking at the `User-Agent` in the request header. It's simple to spoof the `User-Agent` and make this code work, but again, please don't.

Another consideration is that Randall Munroe of xkcd fame has suggested the hit counts on the page are wildly inaccurate:
http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/02/04/trochee-chart/

Comment: Again: thanks for the answer!
But, what can we do if we need some word counts? Wiki is probably fine for English, but for some "smaller" languages word base is not so large. I heard that people used BING for similar purposes, but I doubt that it could be better than Google -- with more accurate counts.

Comment: Nice snippet. :) I replaced Google with Bing and got useful results, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if i misunderstood you, it seems that your question was not about Python but a roundabout to find an updated, accurate, frequency list on billions of words in a specific field (news, literature, web chat, science, etc...).
Since software and processing power are increasing, in Chinese for example there are numerous such frequency lists sorting about 100,000 words out of millions of sentences in a specific field.
That is, for example, instead of asking Google, they take all the movie subtitles available and run a simple algorithm.
The hardest task in Chinese is to determine what a 'word' is, since it's a fuzzy ever changing concept. I guess in most other main languages it must be easier.