# Return the number of results for google search

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a quick way to search Google for a pair of string (like 'married life' and 'happy living' ) and the return the number of results? I can manually do that but  I have huge list of words , would love to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Quite a few results for "google python number of results"

Comment: @vaultah but how would you find out how many, using Python?

Comment: Some of those results: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4785833/2301450), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377504/perform-a-google-search-and-return-the-number-of-results), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3334122/2301450) @jonrsharpe

Comment: @vaultah ...that was a joke!

Comment: In my Python installation, there is a file "Google.py" (I must admit, I am working with Python 3.4). In case you have this library too, I'd propose you to try to use it and to parse the result in your webbrowser. (don't kill me if you don't have this library :-) )

Comment: Found one script ..import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Google Count.')
parser.add_argument('word', help='word to count')
args = parser.parse_args()

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                 params={'q':'"'+args.word+'"',
                         "tbs":"li:1"}
                )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text

Comment: But it works for single word not string.. can you help me out  @vaultah

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search = "django framework"

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params={'q':search})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
res = soup.find("div", {"id": "resultStats"})
print res.text
```

*Output*:

```
About 10,400,000 results
```

**Additional:** If you want the exact number then you can use the following line below:

```
print int(res.text.replace(",", "").split()[1])
```

*Output*:

```
10400000
```

Comment: the problem is that google bans you after X amount of requests. Is there any way to do this without getting banned